# How do I store 0.00 in firestore of firebase databse

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to store the 9.00 in the firebase , but firebase converted into 9 , is there any way to achive this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... 9.00 IS 9

So there is no conversion going on.

It sounds like what you want to do is actually display the number 9 using formatting that shows two decimal places?

If that is the case then this question should be about displaying numbers in your client rather than storing numbers in Firestore.

Comment: Hey Thanks for replay , Actually I have gone so far in front end and take this field of the firestore as double in the front , as am unaware of this behaviour of firebase, So I just wanted to know if any way to store the .00 in the firebase , thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the way you're phrasing the problem it sounds like you are trying to save a monetary amount in Firestore. When storing monetary values, please always store them as whole numbers of the smallest possible increment. So if your currency (like most) has cents as its smaller denominator, store `9.00`  in the database as `900`.

The reason for doing is that most platforms use floating point numbers for manipulating fractional numbers, such as `9.00` and over time this will lead to rounding error. Storing the values as whole numbers prevents this problem.